# Better Filtering on Java Streams

Tags: java, lambda

I need to run filtering on nested Lists and return a List of items from back

I will put a sample code here with my model

```
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ParentModel parent = new ParentModel();
        List<Information> informationList = parent.getChildDatas().stream()
                //Filtering null && empty grandchild
                .filter(childData -> childData.getGrandChildDatas() !=null && !childData.getGrandChildDatas().isEmpty())
                .flatMap(childData -> childData.getGrandChildDatas().stream() )
                //Filtering null && empty information
                .filter(grandChild -> grandChild.getInformations() !=null && !grandChild.getInformations().isEmpty())
                .flatMap(grandChild-> grandChild.getInformations().stream())
                //filtering key
                .filter(information -> information.getKey().equals("SOMETHING"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    @Data
    static class ParentModel {
        private List<ChildModel> childDatas;
    }

    @Data
    static class ChildModel {
        private List<GrandChildModel> grandChildDatas;
    }

    @Data
    static class GrandChildModel {
        private List<Information> informations;
    }

    @Data
    static class Information{
        private String info1;
        private String info2;
        private String key;
    }
}
```

So here you can see, I'm filtering and mapping it back to child streams two times.

Is there alternate way to achieve what I'm trying to do here ??

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edit.  Please see "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)", especially, the "What should I not do?" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should avoid using `null` to represent an empty list.  Use an actual empty list, or even [`Collections.emptyList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()), which is a immutable singleton.  This will avoid the need for `null` checks.

Second, you are filtering by getting a sub attribute, checking conditions on that object, then requesting the same sub attribute in the next step.  Instead, you should `map` to the sub attribute, then filter & process.

```
    ...
    .map(ChildModel::getChildrenDatas)
    .filter(data -> data != null && !data.isEmpty())
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    ...
```

Third, the `.isEmpty()` check is unnecessary, as `.flatMap` works fine with an empty stream.

```
   ...
    .map(ChildModel::getChildrenDatas)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    ...
```

Again, if you don’t use `null` to represent empty lists, the filter line can be removed entirely.

Comment: Unfortunately I wish to avoid null, but the data and data model is provided by 3rd party wrapped in their client code for their server. So i need to live with that